# How to be sure that javascript/jquery always completes click function before returning true (opens link)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I have a click function, for when a user logs out

```
$('#logout').click(function(){

    // update database and tell other users that this person has logged off

});
```

#logout is the id of a link (logout button)

The function will handle some ajax/php/database actions + sending a socketmessage and could easily take several miliseconds to complete

Can I trust that javascript/jquery completes that function before actually returning true (opens the link that is clicked)?

Or what would be a way do to make sure it completes it.. Starting with "return false", and then only return true if it recieves an OK from php for example?

Comment: If you're doing AJAX stuff I suggest you take a look at [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: Always return false and then in the success callback of your Ajax call do the next navigation.

Comment: It doesn't matter how fast the AJAX operation is, since it's asynchronous the JS runtime will stick it in the queue and not get to it at the very earliest till the next time it runs through the queue. The link's handler will always return first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an operation involves AJAX or any async operation, *you can never do a "return"*. Or else, you'd lose the essence of async.

Instead, hand over a callback to execute once it's done. Or return a deferred object and have it listen if ajax is done.

```
$('#logout').click(function(e){
    //store location for later use
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    //prevent link from being followed for now
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({params}).done(function(e){
        //user logged out, follow link
        window.location = location;
    }
}

//while idle and waiting for ajax to complete
//do a moonwalk...
```

Comment: This would work for the ajax part. But I'm also triggering an external jquery function/object, that does'nt seem to return anything, and "done" can't be used.. Would it help if I make the logout link into a button (without default action), and then redirected manually in the function?

Comment: @mowgli that's what the edit does, the part `window.location` does the redirect when done.

Comment: Ok ;) Could I do this?   $('#signout').click(function(){
  var url = "/log/out/";
   if (channel.send) {
  $(location).attr('href',url);
  }
 });   I don't know what the channel.send does excactly (other than sending a message via websocket) since it's from a external minified/compressed js file, but it seems to return true. But I don't know if it returns true only AFTER it completed. Sorry for the mess

Comment: Edit: it only returns true in Chrome. Probably because that browser is so fast at everything, so it performs the channel.send in good time. In other browsers clicking does not redirect. Maybe I should make a new question about how to wait for something to return true. Hm I'm a bit lost